# testing subscribe in karma gives error Argument of type 'Observable<>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Subscription'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this method

```
loadCombos(): void {
  this.combosService.accounts$.subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
    this.list = data;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

and this is my current test:

```
it('should test loadCombos executions ', (done) => {
  combosService = TestBed.inject(CombosService);
  spyOn(combosService.accounts$, 'subscribe').and.returnValue(of(mockList));
  component.loadCombos();
  expect(component.list).not.toBeNull();

  done();
});
```

how can I use mockList on my test, currently I'm getting that's an observable but it needs a suscription, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors here.

One `subscribe()` does not return an `Observable` it returns a `Subscription` like the error says. You could return an `new Subscription()` in your test but that does not make any sense.

If you want to mock the return of your `accounts$`. The correct way is to change `CombosService` for a mocked implementation. [Take a look at the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services).

A fast way to test it will be to overwrite `accounts` directly (if it is not marked as readonly)

```
it('should test loadCombos executions ', (done) => {
  combosService = TestBed.inject(CombosService);
  combosService.accounts$ =  of(mockList);
  component.loadCombos();
  expect(component.list).not.toBeNull();

  done();
});
```

I would not do this though because if `loadCombos()` is called from somekind of button, that implementation is wrong.

Edit: Personally I like to test observables inside `fakeAsync` calls: https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync

Comment: i tried that as well, i get the following error: Argument of type '"accounts$"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. This is an inherited project where I have to make tests, I don't have many options and can't introduce new stuff, so I can't use fakeasync

Comment: fakeAsync already comes with Angular, there is nothing to change. Also I just realized `accounts$` is not a function. Sorry

Comment: @monxas take a look now